# How do I find all data from a table in a specific month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve all data from table in a specific month, my date format in the database table is `2016-06-19` I am need to find with the respect of a selected date, like if I select `2016-05-22`
it will retrieve `2016-05-07` to `2016-06-06` interval values from the table.

And also to all the values in this month which is `05` month, I am using `mysqli` with PHP. I have tried using this query

```
SELECT * FROM t_tenancy_details WHERE
    agreement_date >= DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' )AND
    agreement_date < DATE_FORMAT( CURRENT_DATE, '%Y/%m/01' )
```

This works fine for the running month, But problem is that if I select a previous month it does not work.

Comment: " please don't down vote me I will loss the eligibility of asking" - I'm afraid asking us not to downvote usually has the opposite effect...

Comment: If you say: "...if I select 2016-05-22 it will retrieve 2016-05-07 to 2016-06-06...", then you're not really talking about 'a specific month', are you? It's more like a period of a month around a certain date. Is the latter really what you want?

Comment: @KIKO Software Yes I want that, besides I need to retrieve with the respect of a  specific moth like 5/6/7 or any. but the date in format  like 2016-05-22 
I need the both way

Comment: It is unclear what you are are looking for. Can you explain your date ranges? I am pretty sure you do not want to use DATE_FORMAT in the comparison (you can use it in your select to format your result). You might want to play around with the [date-functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html), e.g. date_add, last_day, month, year,... to calculate your daterange from a given start date according to your logic.

Comment: @Solarflare I am searching Exactly what you said. I want replace in the place of date_format. my variable will be there, it may be any date. I want to set a date by myself and find around it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear from the question as to what is needed. Based on the 2 requirements that I could understand:

1. Get everything surrounding the given date (i.e. +-15 days from the given date):

   ```
   SELECT * 
     FROM t_tenancy_details 
    WHERE agreement_date >= DATE_SUB(@d, INTERVAL 15 DAY)
      AND agreement_date <= DATE_ADD(@d, INTERVAL 15 DAY);
   ```
2. Get all the records where the month is same as the month in the given date:

   ```
   SELECT *
     FROM t_tenancy_details
    WHERE MONTH(agreement_date) = MONTH(@d)
      AND YEAR(agreement_date) = YEAR(@d);
   ```

where @d is the input date, in your case - CURRENT_DATE

Answer (score 0):

Should be this

```
SELECT * FROM t_tenancy_details
WHERE (YEAR(t_tenancy_details) => YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(agreement_date) => MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
AND (YEAR(t_tenancy_details) <= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
AND MONTH(agreement_date) <=  MONTH(CURRENT_DATE))
```